# Script for handling PPA's on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script to handle the PPA's on Ubuntu & derivatives. I was wondering how to know if I'm handling this the right way.

So, the script works (flawlessly), but I posted it to a blog and got this feedback :

> The way you wrote you script is the one we all use when we begin : we don't know the variables, so we use traditionnal commands, and in the end if we remove the "#" arguments from the script, the code is sad *(maybe he meant 'poor' ?)*

Here is a sample :

```
#! /bin/bash
SCRIPT="ppa-tool"
VERSION="2.0.1" 
DATE="2014-03-26"
RELEASE="$(lsb_release -si) $(lsb_release -sr)"

[ -n "`echo "$1" | grep ppa`" ] && PPA=$1
[ -n "`echo "$2" | grep ppa`" ] && PPA=$2

helpsection() 
{ 
echo -e "Usage : $SCRIPT [OPTION]... [PPA]... 
-h, --help     shows this help
-c, --check    check if [PPA] is available for your release

Version $VERSION - $DATE"
exit 0
}

error() { echo -e "$SCRIPT - Oops, something went wrong\nTry « $SCRIPT --help » for more information." && exit 0 ; }

ppa_verification()
{ 
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/$(echo $PPA | sed -e 's/ppa://g')/ubuntu/dists -O /tmp/"$SCRIPT-check.tmp" -q 
if [[ -n "`cat "/tmp/$SCRIPT-check.tmp" | grep $(lsb_release -sc)`" ]] ; then 
    echo -e "$SCRIPT : '$PPA' is available for $RELEASE"
else 
    echo -e "$SCRIPT : '$PPA' is NOT available for $RELEASE"
fi  
rm "/tmp/$SCRIPT-check.tmp"
}

[ "$1" == "--help" ] || [ "$1" == "-h" ] && helpsection

if [ "$1" == "--check" ] || [ "$1" == "-c" ] || [ "$1" == "check" ]  ; then
    [ -n "`echo $2`" ] && ppa_verification && exit 0
    error
fi

error
```

([complete script](http://ubuntuone.com/0unKXUZc917pH5UOsBAPOg) - *[also in French](http://ubuntuone.com/2Y6Azu4xohUbUdldPC1KWi)*)

Apparently, my syntax is bad, but I don't see what I could do to improve this, and I don't understand the feedback I recieved. Could you help me figure it out ?

EDIT: From Unix&Linux (where I first posted, but was redirected here), someone said it wasn't good to use capital letters for variables. So $SCRIPT should become $script.

Comment: @Jamal : are you sure this is a better title than "Bash script : how to know if it's written correctly?" ? Because if the script itself is for PPA's handling, the main reason I'm here is to find out where I'm wrong with my BASH, not with the stuff the script does at the end

Comment: I can assure that this title is better! Here we are doing review so asking for : how to know if it's written correctly is not relevant. And you should not include tag in the title. So yes the title is better.

Comment: OP edited, now the full script is in English, should help the reviewers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### User experience

- `-h`  or `--help` should print the usage message to standard output, which you do.  However, on any unrecognizable command line, you should print the same (or similar) message to standard error and exit with a non-zero status.
- Similarly, other error messages should go to standard error and result in a non-zero status.

#### Style issues

- Good job, double-quoting almost every variable you used.  A lot of shell programmers neglect to do so.
- Good job, breaking the program up into functions.  A lot of shell programmers don't.
- Indent your code consistently.  It's hard to see where your functions begin and end.
- Make use of `case` to replace convoluted `if` statements.
- Do all of your command-line parsing in one place, and have a coherent parsing strategy.  You can either use `getopt` (which has a bit of a learning curve) or build something based on `shift` (which is easier for a beginner to understand).
- You can pass parameters to functions.  Passing `$PPA` to `ppa_verification()` would be more elegant than using a global.

There isn't 100% consensus on whether variable names should be `$ALL_CAPS` or `$lower_case`.  One common convention is `$ALL_CAPS` for global and/or exported variables, `$lower_case` for local or non-exported variables.

#### Use of `wget`

- Instead of writing the output of `wget` to a temporary file, you could just pipe it to `grep` directly: `wget -q -O - "$url" | grep -q "$release"`.
- But then, to distinguish between a `wget` failure (e.g. network problem) and the release not being found by `grep`, you would have to interrogate `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` and `${PIPESTATUS[1]}`, which is a bit complicated.
- Why not try to fetch the subdirectory of `dists/` that you care about instead?  Then you only need to test whether the server returned an HTTP 200 (Success!) or HTTP 404 (Not Found).

```
#! /bin/bash
SCRIPT="ppa-tool"
VERSION="200_success"
DATE="2014-03-26"
RELEASE="$(lsb_release -si) $(lsb_release -sr)"

helpsection() 
{ 
    echo "Usage : $SCRIPT [OPTION]... [PPA]... 
-h, --help     shows this help
-c, --check    check if [PPA] is available for your release

Version $VERSION - $DATE"
}

ppa_verification()
{ 
    local ppa="${1#ppa:}"

    local codename="$(lsb_release -sc)"
    local url="http://ppa.launchpad.net/$ppa/ubuntu/dists/$codename/"

    wget "$url" -q -O /dev/null
    ######################################################################
    # Exit Status
    #
    # Wget may return one of several error codes if it encounters problems.
    # 0 No problems occurred.
    # 1 Generic error code.
    # 2 Parse error--for instance, when parsing command-line options, the `.wgetrc' or `.netrc'...
    # 3 File I/O error.
    # 4 Network failure.
    # 5 SSL verification failure.
    # 6 Username/password authentication failure.
    # 7 Protocol errors.
    # 8 Server issued an error response.
    ######################################################################
    case $? in
      0) # Success
        echo "$SCRIPT : '$ppa' is available for $RELEASE"
        ;;
      8) # HTTP 404 (Not Found) would result in wget returning 8
        echo "$SCRIPT : '$ppa' is NOT available for $RELEASE"
        return 1
        ;;
      *)
        echo "$SCRIPT : Error fetching $url" >&2
        return 3
    esac
}

PPA=
while [ -n "$*" ] ; do
    case "$1" in
      -h|--help)
        helpsection
        exit 0
        ;;
      --check=*)
        PPA="${1#*=}"
        ;;
      -c|--check|check)
        PPA="$2"
        shift
        ;;
      *)
        helpsection >&2
        exit 2
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ -z "$PPA" ]; then
    helpsection >&2
    exit 2
fi

ppa_verification "$PPA"
```

Comment: Thank you !! I don't understand everything but I'll make my homeworks

Comment: There's a little mistake in your $url (from ppa_verification), it should be `local url="http://ppa.launchpad.net/$ppa/ubuntu/dists/$codename/"`

Comment: A mistake in my code or your your code? I thought I was silently fixing a bug.

Comment: Yours. The suggested method is great, but you made a mistake with the url, it shouldn't have '/ppa' inside it.

Comment: Do you expect the user to include `…/ppa` in the parameter then? How else would it work?

Comment: I think you're missing the point : the correct url is `**/$ppa/ubuntu/**`, and NOT `**/$ppa/ppa/ubuntu/**` -> You put a `/ppa` directory in the URL that does not exists on Launchpad

Comment: there is indeed a `/ppa` in http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/ , but do not forget that there is none in http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/saucy/

Comment: I see the `…/ppa` suffix is a convention that some (but not all) PPAs follow, so it would have to be specified on the command line by the user.

Comment: it is specified by the user, always. The convention is ppa:user/directory. With `apt`, for example `apt-add-repository ppa:user/directory`, and it is the same with this script.